# Unable to craft MV-Transformer (Industrial craft 2 experimental + GregTech)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have my custom mod pack with following mods: [mods list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsJGELm4ir_edHNERWNGS1BZTEVaZUJ5XzhsMEprSEE&usp=sharing). The problem is I can't craft MV-Transformer - NEI recipe looks strange:

[image]

... and, of course, doesn't work. And when I try old known recipe - I get nothing:

[image]

How can I craft MV-Transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first picture is an NEI bug. I'd try reinstalling NEI and the NEI plugins to fix that.

The IC2 wiki is out of date as well. Replace the gold cables with copper cables and you should be set:

[image: MV Transformer Recipe]

Comment: Apparently, this recipe in particular, among others, are bugged in IC2 Experimental 1.6.4's NEI plugin, or something. [There's a mod out there that can fix this](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=10433), but I haven't tested it personally.

Comment: You're also [not the only one with this issue](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=10321). It seems to be a bug isolated to IC2 experimental.